# Why can't I run this ruby file?

Tags: ruby

I am on Ubuntu. I have a ruby file that looks like this.

```
class Hangman
  def initialize
    @letters = ('a'..'z').to_a
    @word = words.sample
  end

  def words
    [
      ['cricket', 'A game played by gentlemen'],
      ['Something', 'A cool sentence'],
      ['house', 'This is getting tiring'],
      ['ruby', 'Science has created'],
      ['blah ', 'This is the last one'],
    ]
  end

  def begin
    #ask user for a letter
    puts `new game started... your clue is #{ @word.first }`
    guess = gets.chomp

    puts "You guessed #{guess}"
  end

end

game = Hangman.new
game.begin
```

This ruby file is called "play.rb" inside my current direcory. I check my current working directory and I get

```
/home/ray/Documents/Projects/hangman-game
```

Now I want to run this code by doing this

```
ruby play.rb
```

It doesn't work though. This is the error that I get.

```
play.rb:19:in ``': No such file or directory - new (Errno::ENOENT)
        from play.rb:19:in `begin'
        from play.rb:28:in `<main>'
```

I am sure the file is there. I don't understand why it's not working. Has anyone seen this issue? Also I am using Ruby 3.0.

Comment: Tip: For unchanging things define constants, like `WORDS = [ ... ]` would be better. Each time you call `words` you generate a heap of garbage, a bunch of arrays and strings, that is unnecessary. In this trivial program it's probably not an issue, but that's a bad habit to get into.

Comment: It would also be more convenient if you did `@word, @hint = words.sample`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On line 19 you're using backticks ``` `` ``` rather than a quote mark. The backticks execute the string in the shell and return the result as a string: try replacing it with `pwd` or `ls`. But here you want double-quotes `""`.

There are some clues in the error message that help point you to where the problem is:

- the line number identifies the line,
- the backtick operator is identified as the method call where the error is occurring, and
- "No such file or directory - new (Errno::ENOENT)" indicates that the system is trying to find a command called `new` -- the first word in that string.

Comment: Oh my! Good eye. I have been working with Javascript so much that I didn't see anything wrong with that on ruby. Thanks!

Comment: @this.R.A : Backticks in Javascript are double quotes in Ruby. Interpolation in Javascript (`${...}`) is `#{....}` in Ruby.

Answer (score 1):

Replace:

```rb
puts `new game started... your clue is #{ @word.first }`
```

To:

```rb
puts "new game started... your clue is #{ @word.first }"
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using back-ticks for the message you want to display, but in ruby that is interpreted as a command evaluation, use double quote instead.

Change this:

```
`new game started... your clue is #{ @word.first }`
```

For this:

```
"new game started... your clue is #{ @word.first }"
```